# OpenGL ES 2.0: sharing constants between the main program and shader code

Tags: android, opengl-es

There is a constant I am using both in my main code (Android) and in the shader:

```
// Main code
private static final int XSIZE=16;
private float[] sinusoida = new float[XSIZE];

// shader
const int XSIZE = 16;
uniform float u_SinArray[XSIZE];
```

Both constants refer to the same thing, so obviously it would be optimal to share them and have one automatically change when you change the first one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether the Java code and the shader code can literally access the same variable, then no. Especially if you are using a pre-compiled shader, the answer is no. If you are compiling the shader in your Java code, then you can simply use the Java constant to build the shader script (but it doesn't seem like that's what you're doing). An alternative would be to pass another uniform to the shader instead of using a constant. Assuming it wouldn't put you over the maximum number of uniforms in your shader, that is probably the safest way to go IMO.

Edit:
To future readers, never mind the uniform suggestion. Uniforms are implicitly constant during execution, but not at compile time, which would be necessary for an array declaration.

Comment: @fadden Not to be picky, but I mentioned that.

Comment: Ok, I see. Passing a uniform - notice that I am declaring an array the size of XSIZE later on in my shader, can I declare an array of size passed by a uniform? I don't think so, but let me check. Anyway, even if this works, it would slow down the shader, so this is not the way to go.

Comment: Generating shader code in my Java code - sounds better, although this is always clunky. Currently I am simply writing the shader in a text file which later on a read in my Java code and compile. 

I guess I could read the file and replace the value of XSIZE at this time. Not sure if I want to bother though, this is not such a big problem to write GLSL parsers... I hoped there was a way to define a constant and pass it on to the shader compiler, much like when compiling C code you can define a variable in the makefile and access it in your C code?

Comment: You would be correct. Another uniform wouldn't work. Sorry about the piss-poor suggestion.